# Push array of an objects to array of documents in MongoDB without duplicating the property value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

Current status of MongoDB document:

```
// Team document

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cc6d4c8c3faa84f28e5fe1d"),
    "teamMembers" : [ 
        {
            "player" : ObjectId("5ba24b8594a05f3788980a11"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("5cc6d4c8c3faa84f28e5fe1e")
        }
    ],
    "createdDateTime" : ISODate("2019-04-29T10:41:12.836Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

I have following request data needs to add in teamMembers property of above document:

```
{
    "teamId": "5cc6d4c8c3faa84f28e5fe1d",
    "playerList": [
        {
            "player": "5ba24b8594a05f3788980a11"
        },
        {
            "player": "5ba38151e1baf00264786891"
        },
        {
            "player": "5ba38151e1baf0026478688c"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have tried following moongoose code:

```
Team.update({ '_id': req.body.teamId }, {
        $addToSet: {
            'teamMembers': { $each: req.body.playerList }
        }
    }, function (err) {
        if (err) {
             /* error response */ 
        }
        else {
            /* success response */
        }
    });
```

**Problem:** If player already exist in array then it should not be added toteamMembers array, but in my case its adding duplicate records of player. So in above case `player:5ba24b8594a05f3788980a11` already exist in MongoDB document so it should not be get added but remaining two player should get added in `teamMembers` array

Comment: That's because you are not adding the "_id" (which should be the same as in the existing doc) field along with your player id

Comment: Yes, it is auto generated so unable to identify as same element which we are pushing. But any how I want tpo deal with it @AnirudhSimha

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exact query but below query will work if you were checking one member at a time. You will have to modify this to check the array input in request.

```
Team.findOneAndUpdate({ 
      '_id': req.body.teamId, 
      teamMembers: { $not: { $elemMatch: { player: player1 } } }, 
      $addToSet: { 'teamMembers': player1 } 
});
```

possible solution

```
Team.findOneAndUpdate({ 
      '_id': req.body.teamId,
      teamMembers: { $not: { $elemMatch: { player: { $in : req.body. playerList } } } }, 
      $addToSet: { teamMembers': { $each: req.body.playerList }   
});
```

What this query does? It will find and add a new player in document with '_id' after checking if teamMembers array has player passed in request.